# JS data service load all data or just needed data

Tags: javascript, ajax, odata, datacontext

I am developing a web store with products divided by categories.

Lets say in every category I have something like 300 products. Now, if I want to show those products via ajax (with filtering and paging), what would be best:

1. Pull all the products for a category and than manipulate the list (for filters and paging) from memory?
2. Pull only the needed data each time, means every time I'll change a filter or move to a different page (in paging) of the products, a query will be sent to the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you speaking about categories with less than 500 items it's better to manipulate them on client side. Simple store json object with data and render it with templates.

Comment: Thanks, you think 500 items won't slow down the browser? it should work on all kinds of browsers on all kinds of devices.

Comment: In my app we manipulate with about 1000 items. it start to slow down at about 1500. But we have powerfull machines. If we take regular user with netbook, 500 items won't case any trobles to him